# Run first command on Jenkins Server and second command on the slave?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I have a requirement like I want to execute a script first on the Jenkins Server and the second script on the slave. Is it possible?

The server is up on a Ubuntu machine - the first script will setup the jobs html log file and the second script will run the actual test and stores the log at the end. I need to pass the env variables set by Jenkins to the second script. How can it be done?

Also, Is it possible to send the env variables set in Jenkins Server during run time to the slave and set the same in the slave?

Comment: Why can't the slave do that setup?

Comment: The first script uses some environment variables which is set randomly by the Jenkins (ex: **JENKINS_HOME, JOB_NAME, BUILD_NUMBER, BUILD_ID, PKG_VERSION** and so on). I don't know how to pass those environment variables to the slave and run the script. Is it possible to push the env variables from Jenkins Server to Slave and set those env variables on the slave? If so, I can run the scripts on the slave only.

Comment: I couldn't understand clearly what **XY** problem is. Could you explain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run part of Job on master and the other part on slave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21922524/is-it-possible-to-run-part-of-job-on-master-and-the-other-part-on-slave)

Comment: Perhaps solving the problem of passing that information to the slave is your real problem. That is, you have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)