# Re run Jenkins job on a different slave upon failure

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a job which is compatible with 2 slaves(configured on the different locations). I often experience connectivity issues due to VPN session timeout so I am trying to figure out a way to automatically run a job on the slave 2 if the job  gets fail on slave 1. Please let me know if there is any plugin or any way to accomplish it.

Comment: What kind of configuration are you using in Jenkins: pipeline script, declarative pipeline, free style project, etc ?

Comment: @JRichardsz its a free style project.

Answer (score 1):

I think with a free style project, it would be hard to implement your requirement.

## Pipeline script

Check this if you don't know this plugin : [How create a pipeline script](https://code-maven.com/jenkins-pipeline-hello-world)

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35948853/3957754), the Pipeline Plugin allows you to write jobs that run on multiple slave nodes using **labels**:

```
node('linux') {
  git url: 'https://github.com/jglick/simple-maven-project-with-tests.git'
  sh "make"
  step([$class: 'ArtifactArchiver', artifacts: 'build/program', fingerprint: true])
}
node('windows && amd64') {
  git url: 'https://github.com/jglick/simple-maven-project-with-tests.git'
  sh "mytest.exe"
}
```

I created this simple pipeline script and work (this example does not have label, but you could use it):

```
def exitStatusInMasterNode = 'success';

node {
   echo 'Hello World in node master'
   echo 'status:'+exitStatusInMasterNode
   exitStatusInMasterNode = 'failure'
}

node {
   echo 'Hello World in node slave'
   echo 'master status:'+exitStatusInMasterNode
}
```

**exitStatusInMasterNode** variable could be shared across nodes.

So if your slave1 fail, you could set **exitStatusInMasterNode** to failure. And at the start of your slave2, you could validate if **exitStatusInMasterNode** is failure in order to execute the same build but in this slave.

Example:

```
def exitStatusInMasterNode = 'none';

node {
  try{
    echo 'Hello World in Slave-1'
    throw new Exception('Simulating an error')
    exitStatusInMasterNode = 'success'    
  } catch (err) {
    echo err.message
    exitStatusInMasterNode = 'failure'
  }
}

node {
   if(exitStatusInMasterNode == 'success'){
     echo 'Job in slave 1 was success. Slave-2 will not be executed'
     currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
     return;

   }

   echo 'Re launch the build in Slave-2 due to failure on Slave-1'
   // exec simple tasks or stages
}
```

Log of simulated error in slave1

```
Running on Jenkins in .../multiple_nodes
Hello World in Slave-1
Simulating an error

Running on Jenkins in .../multiple_nodes
Re launch the build in Slave-2 due to failure on Slave-1

Finished: SUCCESS
```

Log when there is not error in slave1 (comment this line: throw new Exception)

```
Running on Jenkins in .../multiple_nodes
Hello World in Slave-1

Running on Jenkins in .../multiple_nodes
Job in slave 1 was success. Slave-2 will not be executed

Finished: SUCCESS
```